# Сбой кодировки при выводе php

Tags: php, utf-8, openserver

Объясните пожалуйста, почему при выводе целого слова получается, а при выводе отдельного символа получается знак вопроса, причем при выводе английского символа работает все правильно.

```
function convert($string)
{
    $test = explode(" ", $string);
    echo $test[1];
    echo $test[1][0];
}
echo convert('привет мир');
echo convert('hello world');
?>
```

Выводы: мир � world w

В .htaccess установлена кодировка utf-8 и в настройках OpenServer тоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте функцию `iconv` для изменения кодировки. [Документация](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.iconv.php)

```
echo iconv('CP1251','UTF-8',convert('Hello world!'));
```

```
function convert($string)
{
    $test = explode(" ", $string);
    echo iconv('CP1251','UTF-8', $test[1]);
    echo iconv('CP1251','UTF-8', $test[1][0]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, подскажите, пожалуйста, почему происходит, что кодировка сбивается при выводе отдельного элемента, а при выводе слова целиком не сбивается?

Comment: У вас не прописана кодировка в `HTML`. Поставьте тег `<meta charset="UTF-8">` в теге `<head>`. Если у вас это сделано то вслепую копать довольно трудно. В ответе я написал принудительное изменение кодировки, обычно оно не требуется.